# Swift != in switch statement

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'm learning Swift and wonder why the following code produces an error ('!=' is not a prefix unary operator):

```
var name: String? = nil

switch name {
case != nil :
    print("Hello \(name!)")
default :
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}
```

It works when I use if else:

```
var name: String? = nil

if name != nil {
    print("Hello \(name!)")
}
else {
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}
```

How can I change my switch statement to make it work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Swift `switch` statements don't accept partial arbitrary expressions. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID129 The error sums it up--you can't put `!=` in front of a value "by itself" to create a valid `case` value.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your specific question.  And maybe you've come across these before.  But, consider another way to write this logic without if/else or switch, in one line, using the [nil coalescing operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html): `print("Hello, " + (name ?? "anonymous"))`. The `??` operator is itself shorthand for a specific usage of the ternary operator, when applied to nil checks:  `c = (a ?? b)` => `c = (a != nil ? a! : b)` => `if a != nil { c = a! } else { c = b }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does it not work? Because a switch statement is supposed to have a list of values to compare to, not expressions:

```swift
let number = 10

switch number {
case 1:
    print("one")
case 2:
    print("two")
default:
    print("too big for me")
}
```

---

How to fix: You can do what @emlai suggested, and use an `if-let` statement:

```swift
if let name = name {
    print("Hello \(name)")
} else {
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}
```

Or, if you need to use a switch statement, you can do any of these:

```swift
//this is as close as to what you are doing
switch name {
case _ where name != nil:
    print("Hello \(name!)")
default:
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}

//this binds name to a non-optional variable called actualName
switch name {
case let actualName where actualName != nil:
    print("Hello \(actualName)")
default:
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}

//this also binds name to actualName, but is more succinct
switch name {
case let actualName?:
    print("Hello \(actualName)")
default:
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with the "supposed". See my answer. Testing key paths in particular is great.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to do that in Swift would be:

```
if let name = name {
    print("Hello \(name)")
} else {
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is with optional binding...

```
var name: String? = nil

switch name {
case let actualName? :
    print("Hello \(actualName)")
default :
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}
```

I’d recommend reading more about optionals and their usage too... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

Comment: this binds `actualName` to an optional, and thus will never reach the default

Comment: `actualName` needs a `?` at the end, to unwrap the optional.

Comment: Thank you, but this actually prints "Hello nil" instead of "Hello, anonymous"... I will definitely do some reading though, thank you for the link!

Comment: Thank  you Fogmeister and @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, the code below works: var name: String? = nil

switch name {
case let actualName? :
    print("Hello \(actualName)")
default :
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica  thanks for that.  I guess that comes from trying to type code into a website on my phone. Haha

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a switch that behaves like an if-else, switch on `true`:

```
switch true {
case name != nil :
    print("Hello \(name!)")
default :
    print("Hello, anonymous")
}
```